# Updating Global Value from a Function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

everybody. I'm working on a project and I have two functions for a slideshow using the same global variable. I want the value to carry between the functions, instead of resetting to 1 every time you switch. Is it possible to permanently update a global variable from a function or do I need to really rethink my code?

Comment: *"Is it possible to permanently update a global variable"* no clue what 'permanently update' means

Comment: @epascarello So when loopOne runs and the value of x is 2, then the user runs loopTwo to move on to 3, is there a way to carry the value from one function to another?

Comment: If they reference the same variable yes....

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be a good idea if you edited your question to include the relevant source code, to make it easier for the community to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Without the code, we can only guess what exactly is your question, because it may change depend on the code.

Comment: @MandyShaw Thank you for that and for responding so quickly! I'll post my code after work.

Answer (score 0):

You basically answered your own question, as long as the variable is global and `let` or `var`. You can't permanently change something in JS. With that being said, let variables can't become const and const variables can become let but you can keep a value inside a function or make it global and change the value of it through a function. Try something like this:

```
let myVariable = 0;

const loopOne = () => {

    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        myVariable++;
    };
  return true;
};

const loopTwo = () => {

    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        myVariable++;
    };
  return true;
};

loopOne();
loopTwo();
```